# Classification of representation-finite symmetric algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory

(Algebras are assumed to be finite dimensional and connected over a field here)
Over an algebraically closed field the classification of representation-finite symmetric algebras is very nice up to stable equivalence. It consists of trivial extensions of hereditary representation-finite algebras and Nakayama algebras of Loewy length $w=qn+1$ for some $q \geq 2$ and penny farthing algebras. Is a classification of representation-finite symmetric algebras possible up to stable equivalence for arbitrary fields?
Of course a classification up to isomorphism or Morita equivalence will not be possible since it contains the classification of division algebras over any field. (but ok, division algebras are nakayama algebras....)
But using stable equivalence, division algebras are no problem anymore.
If the classification is not known or possible, for which fields is it known?

Can you give an example of a representation-finite symmetric algebra that is not stable equivalent to a trivial extension of a hereditary algebra/Nakayama algebra/ penny farthing algebra?
(You may replace symmetric by selfinjective in the questions if you like more generality)

Comment: Just a comment: I would expect that for non-perfect fields a classification of Nakayama algebras is quite hard. So even if you know that something is stably equivalent to the trivial extension of a Nakayama algebra, it might not help as much.